# Change the size of a MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I need to modify the size of a MKMapView to achieve a similar effect like Foursquare app.

In my scrollViewDidScroll method I have:

```
...
if (scrollOffset < -340.0) {
    if (self.mapIsOpen == NO) {
        [self openMapView];
    }
}
...
```

And in my openMapView method I have this one:

```
CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
rect.origin.y = 0;
rect.size.height = maxMapHeight;
self.mapView.frame = rect;
```

This code works fine if I put on my viewDidLayoutSubviews method but doesn't work in openMapView. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find a solution. The if condition has to go in the scrollViewDidEndDragging method.